# How do I send email to all users in a HABTM association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, actionmailer

I'm trying to notify `users` when they are added to a `conversation`. I can access all users by finding the conversation and simply calling `@conversation.users`. In this example it's 3.

```
conversation has_and_belongs_to_many :users
user has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations
```

In my `conversation.rb` model, I'm trying to send an email to each with an `after_save`.

```
  def send_notify_mail
    @conversation = self
    @conversation_users = @conversation.users
    @conversation_users.each do |user|
      ConversationMailer.notify_mail(self.id).deliver
    end
  end
```

I don't get any errors but it's only sending the email to one user, not all of them. Am I attempting to do this in the correct way? Am I supposed to loop through the users in the model?

Comment: Can you `puts` `@conversation.users.count` and see how many users are there?

Comment: Your approach seems perfectly valid, so not exactly sure. Are you certain the loop is executing multiple times? Alternatively, of course, if you can send the exact same email to each user then you may choose to do that with one delivery sent to multiple email addresses.

Comment: The count does equal 3. How would I output the email addresses in the mailer?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Did any of the answers below work?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this

```
ConversationMailer.notify_mail(self.id).deliver
```

be this

```
ConversationMailer.notify_mail(user).deliver
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on how you've defined the `notify_mail` method. However, it's reasonable to assume that your code, as it stands, does **not** pass each user to the method – instead, it's passing the `Conversation` object. You can resolve this in the following manner:

```
@conversation_users.each do |user|
  ConversationMailer.notify_mail(user).deliver
end
```

Again, this is contingent on how your `notify_mail` method is structured, but if it's sending an email to the `User` object its being passed, then this would likely resolve your issue.